# MScharts graph: Overwrite column / bar value

Tags: c#, graph

Ok this might be a newb question but I've only been programming since a few days.
So I took an example chart from MScharts that is a dynamically created graph during run-time, code is as follows:

```
        private void DynamicChartCreation_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a Chart
        Chart1 = new Chart();

        // Create Chart Area
        ChartArea chartArea1 = new ChartArea();

        // Add Chart Area to the Chart
        Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);

        // Create a data series
        Series series1 = new Series();
        Series series2 = new Series();

        // Add data points to the first series
        series1.Points.Add(34);

        // Add data points to the second series
        series2.Points.Add(14);

        // Add series to the chart
        Chart1.Series.Add(series1);
        Chart1.Series.Add(series2);

        // Set chart control location
        Chart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 48);

        // Set Chart control size
        Chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(360, 260);

        // Add chart control to the form
        this.Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[] { this.Chart1 });

    }
```

It is a column chart and I want to be able to change the column values dynamically via a combobox.
The question is how do I overwrite the existing old values?

I tried it with Series.point.add like this:

```
                Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY(comboBox_value);
```

But instead of applying the value to the first series1 column, it creates another column with the new value right next to it.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did customize in my project for axix "X", I paste code here, for your reference...
It's working fine in my environment... Please, check it in your environment.

```
protected void SpiLineAreaChart_Customize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ChartArea area in ((Chart)sender).ChartAreas) {
        foreach (Axis axis in area.Axes) {
            if (axis.Name.StartsWith("X")) {
                foreach (CustomLabel label in axis.CustomLabels) {
                    counter = counter + 1;
                }
                lastpoint = counter;
                midpoint = counter / 2;
                for (int i = 0; i <= counter - 1; i++) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        axis.CustomLabels(i).Text = MonthVal;
                    } else if (i == midpoint - 1) {
                        StartDate = StartDate.AddDays(31);
                        strstartdate = StartDate.ToString("MMM");
                        axis.CustomLabels(i).Text = strstartdate;
                    } else if (i == lastpoint - 1) {
                        StartDate = StartDate.AddDays(31);
                        strstartdate = StartDate.ToString("MMM");
                        axis.CustomLabels(i).Text = strstartdate;
                    } else {
                        axis.CustomLabels(i).Text = "";
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant really do anything with it :/ I'm pretty new and unexperienced. How do I implement it so it works with my chart too?

Comment: you just give comboBox value where i gave monthval and remove remaining code.